# Rope construction of spheres

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Given the following theorem:

[image][image]

where the first variational formula is given by:

[image]

I don't understand why the second term involving the integral of the variational formula vanishes in this case. Is it missing in the statement of the theorem that $\gamma_t$ is a geodesic for all t or why else does that term vanish?

Comment: Why is $X(t)=\gamma_t'(0)$ defined and then never referred to again?

Comment: Also, taking $M=\mathbb R$, $\gamma_t(s) = t\cdot s$ gives you $\eta(t)=t$, so $\eta'(t)=\partial_t$ and $\gamma_t'(1)=t\partial_t$, their scalar product is not zero. There quite a few details missing if you want anybody to understand what you are even looking at here.

Comment: @s.harp: I had trouble with sloppiness the last time OP copied part of that text. I wonder what it is.

Comment: @TedShifrin Yes I agree, it's very sloppy. It's from the lecture notes of a course I took: https://www3.math.tu-berlin.de/geometrie/Lehre/WS18/DGII/script_differentialgeometry.pdf